# How can I send a SharePoint alert only when a particular column is changed?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-alerts

I need to trigger alert, if value of particular column (say marks<8, send mail to manager) changes.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Some kinds of lists (e.g. tasks) allow to **send alerts when someone changes an item that appears in a particular view**. Read the article [Use SharePoint Filtered Views to Stop Sending Alerts to Yourself](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/04/use-sharepoint-filtered-views-stop-sending-sharepoint-alerts-to-yourself/) to get all the details (appropriate section begins with *Well you need to set up a filtered view*).

If you list supports this feature, first create a view that shows only the items that satisfy your `marks<8` condition and then configure an alert that uses this view.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an event handler on the list to do this : 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Chandresh.P/EventHandler04292009070324AM/EventHandler.aspx